# Fisher Information in LAD model for ML estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, fisher-information, least-absolute-deviations

Considering an i.i.d. sample from a linear model $y_i=\alpha x_i+u_i$ (both $y$ and $x$ are centered with respect to their means) errors are homoscedastic and are distributed as:
$$u\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}{|u_i|}}{\sigma}}$$
How do I calculate the Fisher Information for $\hat\alpha_{ML}$ (maximum likelihood estimator for $\alpha$)?

Comment: I guess that $\hat\alpha_{ML}$ has to be related somehow with the median of $x$ and $y$, but I'm not sure how precisely.

Comment: Trying to compute the second der of the likelihood fnct, I apparently arrived to the conclusion that the Fisher Information has to be null:
$$ln(L(y|x,\alpha,\sigma))=-n\ln(\sqrt{2\sigma^2})-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i-\alpha x_i|\\
\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \alpha}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(y_i-\alpha x_i)(-x_i)}{|y_i-\alpha x_i|}\\
\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \alpha^2}=0$$
Obviously $L$ is not differentiable when $\alpha=\frac{y_i}{x_i}$, so I'm not  sure that this is the right way to proceed to compute the Fischer Information for $\hat\alpha_{ML}$.